# Vector Grid Creates just one grid

Tags: qgis, vector-grid, grids-graticules

Im trying to create a vector grid for my shapefile. I want it to be in meters so I set my CRS to EPSG:32650 UTM 50N. This is what I do exactly

[image]

I set the layers CRS to that one above, then click on vector grid and set extents based on the layer I then put 50m as my horizontal and vertical spacing then click run. This is what comes out. Its just a single box with the same grid spacing I put

[image]

Hoping someone could help me on this

Answer (score 2):

It does not work like that. It seems your data is not is UTM Zone 50N and it looks like it is in WGS 84 based on the coordinates of the canvas. You need to save as the vector layer as UTM Zone 50N. To do that right-click the vector layer in the table of content -> Save As -> Under CRS Choose EPSG:32650, Give a name to the output file and click OK.

[image]

Then load the newly created shapefile of EPSG:32650 into new QGIS project and go to Vector -> Research tools -> Vector grid -> Grid Extent (Use from layer) and choose the vector layer as its extent -> Then specify the 50 m for both x and y spacing.

[image]

Comment: Please accept the answer, this is the proper way to say thanks.